# Sitecore SXA Location finder component not working correctly

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA's Location Finder component for searching but Google Auto-Completion is not working.

Normally it should work like this:

[image]

The Map is working but auto-suggestion is not working correctly. It shows requests in Browser Network Tab but does not render. See the attached image for reference:
[image]

But right now, it is not suggesting any City or Country. How to make it work, thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you added needed APIs for Google Maps? Check my blog post for further details -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/09/07/sitecore-sxa-set-google-maps-for-map-component-with-latest-pricing-changes

Comment: @PeterProcházka I have added all the API Keys already but still, it is not working. The map is working not the auto-suggestion. And it is not a duplicate of that question. Thanks

Comment: Have you specified "Key" field in /sitecore/content/{tenant}/{site}/Settings/Maps Provider item?

Comment: Yes, I have provided the key. I did some changes to the question it will help you to get the situation. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @PrabhatSharma I've checked this on the latest code and it works fine. Do you have any console errors? Are you using custom theme with custom scripts which can interfere with SXA ones?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I also think of that. So I created a new site under the new tenant with in-box SXA features. But still, Location Finder is not showing the auto-complete dialog box. Also, I am not able to search any POI using Zipcode, it is only working with City name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in SXA 1.7.0. It is a problem in the `component-search-location-filter.js` file. It was fixed in SXA 1.8.0. It can be fixed by requesting a patch from Sitecore Support quoting 247292, or taking a new version of this file from a SXA 1.8+.

Comment: Hi Mark, I copied the component-search-location-filter.js from SXA 1.8 and attached it to SXA 1.7. Still, it is throwing the same issue. Also, I am not able to search using Zip Codes while doing so it throws this error "component-search-location-filter.js:219 Error while getting '67000' location". Do you have any idea about this? And one more thing can you please provide me that Sitecore support patch 247292. Thanks.

Comment: Patch 247292 isn't published so I can't provide it. As for changing to Zip Code search, you have to modify `google-maps-connector.js` and change to `autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({input : queryParams.text, types: ['(regions)']`

Comment: I did that change in `google-maps-connector.js` (changes are: `autocomplete.getPlacePredictions[{input : queryParams.text, types: ['(regions)']}, function(results)`] but still I am not able to search using Zip Codes, it is working fine with Region or the City name. I want all three parameters will work (Zip code, region, and city).

Comment: Check out the google maps api docs, this isn't really SXA specific - although would be nice if SXA supports these scenarios OOTB.

Comment: Sure, I will look at it, thanks for the help.